# Is there a better way to give a string choice to a user?

Tags: string, excel, vba

I am using VBA to process a bunch of data. Because the data isn't clean, occasionally I need to make the user manually choose which is correct. Prefer to avoid user form if I can. (although will do it if that's the best way). 
Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub string_choice()
Dim msgValue
msgValue = MsgBox("Hello, which is correct? Choose:" _
& vbCr & "Yes: if you want option A" _
& vbCr & "No: if you want option B" _
, vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion)

If msgValue = vbYes Then
MsgBox "You chose option A"
ElseIf msgValue = vbNo Then
MsgBox "You chose option B"
ElseIf msgValue = vbCancel Then
MsgBox "script closing, no choice made."
End If
End Sub
```

How can I best grab up a couple of strings and ask the user to pick one?

Comment: `inputbox$("Enter option A or B" ...)` ? - A UserForm with a ComboBox would be the most intuitive.

Comment: `MsgBox` is a good solution if you are sure that you won't have more than 3 choices; `Inputbox` might be interesting if you have more, but you'll need to check the output for validation (caution). And the next best solution is an UserForm with dynamically generated Options boxes which is pretty heavy!

Answer (score 1):

*better way* is a matter of perspective.
If better means "less programming effort" then keep it that way.
If better mean "more user-friendly", then I would do the effort and build a user form with a single-selection ListBox. This is even better than a ComboBox because the user can see all the choices and just click the correct one.